# Styling in Vaadin with css

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I am trying to edit the Text of the textfield in [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home).  I created a file (\WebContent\VAADIN\themes\loginthemes\style.css) with ONLY the following information:

```
textstyle      {  
   font-family: HelveticaRounded; 
   font-size: 40px;
   font-style: bold;
}
```

And inside my java file I have the following:

```
TextField username = new TextField("Username: ");
username.setStyleName("style");
// I also tried username.setStyleName("loginthemes");
```

The text for the textfield stays the same.

Answer (score 5):

As Jan Galinski said, you should define a proper theme.
For one named "logintheme" you should create *VAADIN/theme/logintheme/style.scss* as :

```
@import "../reindeer/reindeer.scss";
.logintheme {
    @include reindeer;

    .textstyle {  
        font-family: HelveticaRounded; 
        font-size: 40px;
        font-style: bold;
    }
}
```

Tell the UI to use it:

```
@Theme("logintheme")
    public class MyUI extends UI {
}
```

Also, your usage of **setStyleName()** is incorrect: the parameter is the name of your CSS class, not the name of the theme.
So in your case, it should be:

```
TextField username = new TextField("Username: ");
username.setStyleName("textstyle");
```

Comment: I don't know what is your error (your comment is incomplete); but I've made a change to my example that should make it more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the theme on your UI class.

```
@Theme("logintheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {
}
```

also, you should reference an existing theme via @import, else your theme will look very "reduced".